# this$10 Tree using Node Array

Tags: java, reference, tree, nested

I'm trying to implement a tree using a nested Node, which itself has a Node array.
(see the code bellow)
When I instantiate it and debug it I can see a reference inside the start Node that is called this$0, it basically seems to be the same reference as the instantiated Tree itself. I was wondering if anyone could tell me why it is there and what purpose it serves (if it is not due to some mistake in the code). Thanks.

```
public class NodeTree {
    private Node start;
    private int degree;

    public NodeTree() {
        start = new Node();
    }

    private class Node {
        private Object root;
        private Node[] subtrees;
        private int size;

        Node() {  }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see `this$_something_` in a debugger, it means that your class has a reference to the object of an outer class. This reference is created automatically by the compiler.

In your code this happens because `Node` is a *non-static* class that is nested inside the `NodeTree` class. This means that it gets a reference to its outer object, i.e. the `NodeTree` set automatically.

If you do not want this behavior, make `Node` static in the `NodeTree`, or move it out to make it a top-level class:

```
public class NodeTree {
    private Node start;
    private int degree;

    public NodeTree() {
        start = new Node();
    }
    static private class Node {
//  ^^^^^^
        private Object root;
        private Node[] subtrees;
        private int size;
        Node() {  }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I found some reading on it, and it says that it should only be non-static if its instances need to access non-static members of its enclosing class. Would an example of this be if the inner Node class needs to make a calculation and thus access fields of the enclosing class? thank you

Comment: @NaC114 You would make `Node` non-static if you needed to access some of its enclosing `NodeTree` object - for example, the `start` field.